# Fastest way to search for 2 different values in assembly

Tags: c, performance, assembly, x86

I want so search an assembly buffer for one of two given values, **that differs only by one bit**. let's say `0xfefefeff`and `0xfefefefe` (In other words - the lsb doesn't matter for the search)

The length of the buffer varies.

I thought about two possible ways for that task:

way #1:

```
mov eax, 0xfefefeff
test eax, eax
repne scasd
...
mov eax, 0xfefefefe
test eax, eax
repne scasd
```

way #2:

```
mov eax, 0xfefefefe
lblSearch:
mov esi, [edi] ; edi - the buffer
and si, 0fffeh
cmp eax, esi
...
add edi, 4
loop lblSearch
```

I tried to measure execution time using `QueryPerformanceCounter`and `visual studio diagnostic tools` on those `__asm` snippets in `C` but couldn't find a consistent result. Performance in this issue is extremely important.

Any thoughts of what will be a better way to accomplish that?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a worst case of two compares per data sample, which is very likely memory-bond performance.

Comment: How big is your buffer?

Comment: so x86 on top of an operating system?  measuring performance will be difficult at best.  you have to and and compare obviously, so either try to do larger reads in one transaction and maybe burn more instructions or burn fewer instructions and do more data accesses.  dont think there is a real shortcut to that.

Comment: What instruction set extensions can you use?

Comment: One generic way you can try is to `or` each value with a mask and only compare to the value that has the bit you or'ed in set.

Comment: It's sort of pity you don't show what happens when value is found/not found, often its effect may become organic part of the search code.

Comment: Note that as a first step, you might want to get rid of the `loop` instruction. `loop` is microcoded and slower than a `dec`/`jnz` pair.

Comment: If you want the fastest performance use C/C++ code as the compiler can generate much better code than you. It won't make mistakes like using the LOOP instruction, and it knows how to do things like unroll loops and use SIMD instructions.

Comment: For this specific case [i.e. values], in #2, change `and si,0xfffeh` into `and esi,eax` and it should work. Whether [once fixed] it will be faster is another matter

Comment: xor them, count the "1"s then find if its only 1 "1", by using 256-entry look-up table to check 4xbytes of 32bit value

Comment: @CraigEstey it will not, that would catch many more values, including `~0`. At first I thought the same. Then I had to introduce `edx` in my answer for proper masking.

Answer (score 1):

In your way #2 `and si,imm16` is a problem, It's partial 16b write into `esi` and then the next `cmp eax,esi` requires back composed 32b value, this will cause havoc to register aliasing and dependencies.

Rather do `and esi,0xfffffffe`, it works with `esi` only, so no aliasing/copying/composing is needed internally.

And you may want to unroll it, especially if the size of buffer is divisible by some nice number, otherwise do some prologue to align it.

And don't use `loop`, it's artificially slow.

Also depending what you do in found/not_found case, it may be possible to write that without branching inside the inner loop (for example to count number of such values).

So way #2 rewritten:

```
    ; search for values 0xfefefefe and 0xfefefeff
    mov eax, 0xfefefefe
    mov edx, 0xfffffffe
    ; edi = buffer
    ; ecx = number of elements in buffer
lblSearch:
    mov esi, [edi] ; edi - the buffer
    add edi, 4
    and esi, edx
    cmp esi, eax
    jne lblNotFound
    ... one of values found
lblNotFound:
    dec ecx
    jnz lblSearch
```

This is by no means pushing it to the limit, for that you didn't disclose enough information. If the performance is so extremely important, it may be worth to unroll this, etc..

Or even check the overall architecture to see, if it's possible to catch such values already at producer, without any searching at all.

This is just considerably faster "way #2" than yours, nothing more.